# vb6 to vb.net conversion 'FileName' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox'

Tags: vb.net, vb6

After converting VB6.0 code to VB.Net code, getting the error 'FileName' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox'.

VB6 code after conversion-

```
Public WithEvents rtfLicenseFile As System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox    

Private Sub cmdClose_Click(ByVal eventSender As System.Object, ByVal eventArgs As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdClose.Click
    If Not rtfLicenseFile.ReadOnly Then
        rtfLicenseFile.SaveFile(rtfLicenseFile.FileName, Windows.Forms.RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText)
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()
        Sleep(1000)
    End If
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Yep,  'FileName' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `FileName` is not a member of [System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.aspx). Use a variable to store the filename instead.

For example with your code:

```
Public WithEvents rtfLicenseFile As System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox
Public strFileName As String = "C:\Test.txt"

Private Sub cmdClose_Click(ByVal eventSender As System.Object, ByVal eventArgs As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdClose.Click
    If Not rtfLicenseFile.ReadOnly Then
        rtfLicenseFile.SaveFile(strFileName, Windows.Forms.RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText)
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()
        Sleep(1000)
    End If
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```